# vector<char> VS vector<bool> in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

Why should we use `vector<char>` instead of `vector<bool>`? What is the reason that `vector<char>` is faster?

Comment: @101010 https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool

Comment: @M.M Thanx, I missed that one.

Comment: why should who use? people use both of them and that's why this is primarily opinion based

Answer (score 11):

`std::vector<bool>` is a specialisation of `std::vector<T>` that's done mainly for space efficiency (debatable). However, **it behaves similarly but not equally as a regular `std::vector<T>`**. This is attributed mainly to the fact that `std::vector<bool>` is not a container in the usual C++ standard library sense but rather an array of bits. Some of the differences between a `std::vector<bool>` and a regular `std::vector` are:

- `std::vector<bool>::iterator` is not a random-access iterator.
- `std::vector<bool>` is not required to store its elements as a contiguous array.
- `std::vector<bool>` exposes `class std::vector<bool>::reference` as a method of accessing individual bits. In particular, objects of this class are returned by `operator[]`, `std::vector<bool>::front`, `std::vector<bool>::back` by value.
- `std::vector<bool>` does not use `std::allocator_traits::construct` to construct bit values.
- `std::vector<bool>` does not guarantee that different elements in the same container can be modified concurrently by different threads.
- `std::vector<bool>` has a different interface (i.e., `flip()`)

These differences except from breaking the conceptual meaning of `std::vector` as a contiguous container, have also a tendency to break user code, especially when this code is generic (i.e., template code).

To clarify consider the following example:

```
template<class T> void foo(std::vector<T> &v) {
 T &frnt = v.front();
 ...
}
```

The above example works for every `T` except when `T = bool`. As already mentioned, the reason for this failure is that `v.front()`'s returned value is a temporary (returns by value) and as such cannot bind to a reference.

To avoid this havoc many coders avoid the use of `std::vector<bool>` and prefer the use of `std::vector<char>`. Due to the many problems caused, it is stated by many that use of `std::vector<bool>` could be considered as a premature optimisation. To the resolution of that matter there are proposals from many distinguished C++ community members. One of these proposals suggests to remove `std::vector<bool>` under a different name that it will not refer to C++ standard library containers.

Now to the time performance issue, the main problem with `std::vector<bool>` is that its respective `std::algorithm` algorithms are not optimised for it. Thus, although you might gain space by using it, it's use might lead to a very significant speed pessimization.

### Bibliography

1. [vector: More Problems, Better Solutions, Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/N1211.pdf)
2. [On `vector<bool>`, Howard Hinnant](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool)
3. [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

Comment: Why is it debatable? I believe it is space efficient. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 5):

`vector<bool>` is an array of bits. `vector<char>` is an array of bytes. The former uses less space in exchange for more complicated indexing operations.

Whether `vector<char>` is actually faster or not is probably a function of architecture, especially cache. If your `vector<bool>` fits entirely in L1 cache on x86_64 it could be faster than a `vector<char>` which doesn't.

Usual advice applies, if the performance matters, measure the performance in your application.

Answer (score 2):

> Why should we use `vector<char>` instead of `vector<bool>`?

Usually, you wouldn't want to prefer `vector<char>`.

> What is the reason that `vector<char>` is faster?

Usually, `vector<char>` tends to be slower.

---

Let us discus the drawbacks of `vector<bool>`.

> [cppreference:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety) Different elements in the same container can be modified concurrently by different threads, except for the elements of `std::vector<bool>`

If you need concurrent modification to separate elements within the same container, then a `std::vector<bool>` must be protected by a lock, while a `vector<char>` does not. The simpler code for `vector<char>` is a clear advantage, and may be more efficient assuming high parallelism. If you do have this scenario, don't forget to consider false sharing, though and don't forget to measure.

---

Howard Hinnant has written an [article](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool) that discusses the pros and cons of `vector<bool>`. Short version of pros:

> It is often both a space and speed optimization over the array of bools data structure if properly implemented.

Short version of cons:

> However it does not behave exactly as an array of bools, and so should not pretend to be one.

The argument of the article is not that you shouldn't use `vector<bool>`, but that `vector<bool>` should be something other than a specialization of vector, since it doesn't fully conform to the interface that it specializes.

Comment: Sorry for commenting then removing, but I corrected my tests. So I don't know what "usually" means for you. I created a test that linearly writes then reads with various element types. Conclusion was that writing with bool is faster by a factor of 1.2 than the second place (char or uint_fast8_t), but reading is slower by a factor of 1.6 than the second place (uint_fast8_t). And reads *usually* more frequent than writes. :-)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3JcMHCi9