# Using new to allocate contiguous space vs using a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, dynamic, memset

Why use a new memory location like this when we have vectors?
Are there any Advantages?

```
bool* arr = new bool(size);
```

I am not clear what this line does but what I feel is 
this `std::memset` sets whatever `param2` is given over all
locations starting from address at `param1` and ends at the
given size

```
std::memset(arr, 0, sizeof(bool) * (num+1));
```

Comment: Your title and content doesn't match, please clarify what are you trying to do.

Comment: bool* arr = new bool(size); is not an array.

Comment: Really sorry I am new to c++ programming, is the bool* arr = new bool(size); not creating a contiguos space?

Comment: the correct form would be using square brakets [ ] to create an array see link http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/524357a70fc95b537f31f5d7ec3e8bb8#file-sieve-cpp-L12, I am learning this.

Comment: @basslo that part I know, I am studying an algorithm that has the above lines and actually when the concept was being explained, it was explained as an array will hold all the numbers... so I assumed(like an array) it is a contiguos space

Comment: `bool *arr = new bool(size)` dynamically allocates a single `bool`, and initialises that `bool` using `size`.   The result of the initialisation depends on what `size` is.  If it is of a type that can't be implicitly converted to `bool`, the result is a compilation error.    If you want to dynamically allocate an array and `size` is of integral type, use `bool * arr = new bool[size]`  (square brackets).

Comment: @Peter So if something has a size that is more size than a mem block to hold a single value, wouldn't that be (kind of) an array?

Comment: it is important to understand the similarity between array and pointer arr[5] is equivalent to *(arr+5) for example. You can always write beyound your array size but this can be very dangerous (undefined behavior).

Comment: Because `std::vector<bool>` uses special packing people often avoid it. You can simply use `std::vector<char>` as a `'bool'` *array* which keeps the advantages of using a `std::vector`. (`bool` is actually implemented as a `char`)

Comment: the problem that std::vector<char> occupies more memory than std::vector<bool> since std::vector<bool> is optimized so every element doesn't occupy a byte but a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What this line `bool* arr = new bool(size);` does?

This line allocates a boolean in the heap and it initializes it to `true` if `size != 0` and to `false` if `size == 0`. It then assigns the address of the newly allocated boolean to the boolean pointer `arr`. So no arrays in to play here.

> How I could allocate an array of boolean with `new`?

The proper way to allocate an array in the heap is to use operator `new[]`. That is in your case:

```
bool* arr = new bool[size];
```

With the advent of smart pointers you could also use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<bool[]> arr(new bool[size]);
```

Thus, you wouldn't have to `delete []` afterwards.

> Why use a new memory allocation like this when we have vectors?

Well with any other type except `bool` I would agree but the thing is that there are certain issues with `std::vector<bool>`.

`std::vector<bool>` is a specialisation of `std::vector<T>` that's done mainly for space efficiency (debatable).

However, **it behaves similarly but not equally as a regular `std::vector<T>`**. This is attributed mainly to the fact that `std::vector<bool>` is not a container in the usual STL sense but rather an array of bits. Generaly, use of `std::vector<bool>` can cause many havocs it's considered a premature optimization and it can even pessimize your performance (see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41761131/2352671)).

Another thing is that in embeded systems that space is crusial, using a raw array instead of a vector is a better option in terms of space efficiency.

> What about `std::memset(arr, 0, sizeof(bool) * (size));`?

[`std::memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) initializes a certain number of bytes in memory (i.e., third input argument) with a given value (i.e., second input argument) starting from address `arr` (i.e., first input argument). In the example above it will fill `arr` with `0`s up to `size` number of bytes. That is if `arr` is an array of size `size` it will initialize all the elements of this boolean array to `false`.

However alternatevely, you could use the following scheme:

```
bool* arr = new bool[size]();
                          ^^
```

or

```
std::unique_ptr<bool[]> arr(new bool[size]());
```

And thus avoid calls to raw memory manipulators a `std::memset` that fall in the use with caution category.

Comment: wow, your answer is cool, but can't upvote :p I don't have enough points. Points taken: 1. new bool(size) <- size variable here is misleading and this is just used to create a single memory instance with t/f. 2. This alg's author simply cleared up the folowing memory space directly by allocating zero's doing suc thing is bad!!, but I think as it the heap's leftover mem, he/she didn't bother, stacks mem would have been disaster. 3. Have to use smart pointers to create such stuff.

Answer (score 4):

> Why use a new memory location like this when we have vectors?

We cannot kow why the author used new here. The idiomatic way would be to use a `std::vector<bool>`

> Are there any Advantages?

Usually not, but particularly `std::vector<bool>` is problematic because there is a specialization that doesn't work as for other types.

There are many questions like this on SO:

- [Why vector::reference doesn't return reference to bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399417/why-vectorboolreference-doesnt-return-reference-to-bool)

> I am not clear what this line does but what I feel ...

Your guts are right.

---

Note: The code to allocate a contiguous array of `bool`s with `new` would be

```
bool* arr = new bool[size];
```

Instead of a raw pointer you can use a smart pointer to allocate the array and don't need to care about the `delete []`:

```
std::unique_ptr<bool[]> arr{new bool[size]};
```

Comment: Would `std::array` be better if `size` is known?

Comment: @EdHeal Probably yes.

Comment: Yes totally right author'd used an array if the size was known, but in the algorithm that I am studying https://gist.github.com/anonymous/524357a70fc95b537f31f5d7ec3e8bb8#file-sieve-cpp-L12 the size of the array is decided by the user's input. FYI the link is a part of the whole actual file typed in by me

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ didn't understand this: __particularly std::vector<bool> is problematic because there is a specialization that doesn't work as for other types.__

Comment: @Ramachandrajr I'll add a link.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ  Your guts are right. :p thanks for that bro!

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ thanks for the link, from the link I understood that putting t/f (1/0) straight out using vector could cause memory related problems like the computer may think of it as a different piece of data rather than a straight out vector, so It's better to use 'new' and make use of heap vs other vector, deque options. Thanks a loooot!

Comment: @Ramachandrajr With c++17 the `bool` array can be created with [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) that one no longer has to struggle with the corresponding `delete[]`.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ Thanks for the tip bro, will be using smart pointers from now on